# how to avoid that callback is sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, delegates, callback, calendar, dealloc

The following process leads to a crash of my app:

- the user opens a view and a request is send to the server
- the request is executed in background
- the user navigates back to the root view
- the request has been finished

and the following code is executed

```
// MyDatasource.m  
// e.g. in connectionDidFinishLoading  
[callback loadedDataSource:self];
```

In the meantime the other models/views has been deallocated and the message is sent to a deallocated instance.

`callback` is of type `id` and conforms to the `KalDataSourceCallbacks` protocoll.

How can I avoid that a message is sent to a deallocated object?

PS: My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720087/handle-when-callback-to-a-dealloced-delegate)

**Edit:**

I'll try to set `callback` to nil in the `dealloc` method (in my datasource class). This doesn't solve the problem, because `MyDataSource` is always present and the `dealloc` method should only be called if `RootViewController` is released (what should happen when the app is closed).

What I've done so far:

Now `MyDataSource` is retained by a property in my `RootViewController`:

```
// RootViewController.h
@property (retain) MyDataSource *dataSource;

// RootViewController.m
@synthesize dataSource;
// ...
self.dataSource = [[[MyDataSource alloc] init] autorelease];
kal.dataSource = dataSource;

- (void)dealloc {
    [dataSource release];
    // ...
}
```

> KalViewController does not retain its datasource. You probably will want to store a reference to the dataSource in an instance variable so that you can release it after the calendar has been destroyed.

I also created a `callback` property:

```
// MyDataSource.h
@property (retain) id<KalDataSourceCallbacks> callback;

// MyDataSource.m
@synthesize callback;
// ...
- (void)presentingDatesFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate delegate:(id<KalDataSourceCallbacks>)delegate {
    // ...
    self.callback = delegate;
}
- (void)dealloc {
[callback release];
callback = nil;
   // ...
}
```

Currently the app is not crashing. I have to test on the devices. Adding `callback = nil` doesn't do anything here, because the dealloc is never called.

How should I release `MyDataSource` after the calendar has been destroyed? That doesn't work because I don't know if the calendar has been destroyed. So the dataSource can only live over the whole app runtime.

**Edit 2:**

Can I check `callback` for `nil` to find out if it has been released?

```
if (callback != nil)
     [callback loadedDataSource:self];
```

This doesn't help.

**Edit 3:**

The app was not crashing because I retained the delegate:

```
@property (retain) id<KalDataSourceCallbacks> callback;
```

should be

```
@property (assign) id<KalDataSourceCallbacks> callback;
```

So how could I avoid that the method `loadedDataSource` is sent to a deallocated object for my special case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `KalDataSource.h` I added the following method to the `KalDataSource` protocoll:

```
@protocol KalDataSource <NSObject, UITableViewDataSource>
    // ...
    - (void)destroyCallback;
@end
```

In `KalDataSource.m` I added the method to get rid of the warnings:

```
@implementation SimpleKalDataSource
// ...
- (void)destroyCallback
{
    // do nothing
}
@end
```

In `KalViewController.m` I'm calling my before created method when the object is deallocated:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    // ...
    [dataSource destroyCallback];
}
```

In `MyDataSource.m` I'm implementing the function

```
- (void)destroyCallback {
    self.callback = nil;
}
```

and set the delegate to nil.

Answer (score 1):

when you move out of the current view set the delegate to nil.

Comment: The delegate is in `MyDataSource` class.

Comment: You could access it as a @property. Still not sure whether this is the preferred way to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that you finish the connection and release it and set it to nil.
A message sent to a nil object is ignored.

Comment: The connection can be finished, because my datasource class is created in the `RootViewController` and so always available. (I haven't found another solution for integrating Kal calendar.) So the release of the datasource class is done when `RootViewController` is released.

Comment: One possibility would be to set the delegate to `nil` in the `dealloc` method of `KalViewController`. This would be possible through sending a message or with the help of the notification center. But then I would have to modify `KalViewController` which isn't the best solution. In detail, if I want to upgrade to a newer version, each modification has to be done again (perhaps by a person not mine). But this would be the last possibility to get this work.

Comment: You've also to be aware of retain cycles. Either I take a weak reference or use the observer pattern ...