# How to enable NSZombie in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, nszombie

I have an app that is crashing with no error tracing. I can see part of what is going on if I debug, but can't figure out which object is "zombie-ing".

Does anybody know how to enable NSZombie in Xcode 4?

Answer (score 445, accepted):

Environment variables are now part of the "scheme".

To edit the scheme and turn on zombies:

- In the "Product" menu, select "Scheme" > "Edit Scheme...".
- Go to the "Run Foo.app" stage in the left panel, and the "Arguments" tab on the right.
- Add `NSZombieEnabled` to the "Environment Variables" section and set the value to `YES`, as you could in Xcode 3.

---

**In Xcode 4.1 and above**, there's also a checkbox on the "Diagnostics" tab of the "Run" stage to "Enable Zombie Objects".

---

**With Xcode 6.4:**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Doesnt break on the call to the deallocated object on device, any way to make that happen?

Comment: It changed again in 4.2, see my answer below. Go to Product->Edit Scheme->Diagnostics

Comment: In Xcode, in the Help menu at the top (last one on the right) search for "Edit Scheme" it will point you in the right direction every time in any version.

Comment: If we enable this NSZombieEnabled feature to our app shall we release the app to store..? Because I saw one post saying that its not good practice to release to store when we enable this feature.

Comment: For the rookies coming after, in Xcode 6.1 you go menu Product> Scheme-Edit Scheme>Diagnostics tab>Checkbox Enable Zombie Objects

Answer (score 146):

I encountered the same problem with troubleshooting EXC_BAD_ACCESS and had hard time to find the setting with Xcode 4.2 (the latest one that comes with iOS5 SDK). Apple keeps on moving things and the settings are no longer where they used to be.

Fortunately, I've found it and it works for the device, not just Simulator. You need to open the Product menu in the Xcode, select Edit scheme and then choose the Diagnostics tab. There you have "Enable Zombie Objects". Once selected and run in debugger will point you to the double released object! Enjoy!

In short

```
Product->Edit Scheme->Diagnostics-> Click Enable Zombie Objects
```

Comment: In Xcode, in the Help menu at the top (last one on the right) search for "Edit Scheme" it will point you in the right direction every time in any version.

Answer (score 43):

Product > Profile will launch Instruments and then you there should be a "Trace Template" named "Zombies". However this trace template is only available if the current build destination is the simulator - it will not be available if you have the destination set to your iOS device.

Also another thing to note is that there is no actual Zombies instrument in the instrument library. The zombies trace template actually consists of the Allocations instrument with the "Enable NSZombie detection" launch configuration set.

Comment: "However this trace template is only available if the current build destination is the simulator".  Thank you!

Comment: In Xcode, in the Help menu at the top (last one on the right) search for "Edit Scheme" it will point you in the right direction every time in any version.

Answer (score 25):

It's a simple matter of setting an environment variable on your executable `(NSZombieEnabled = YES)`, and then running/debugging your app as normal.If you message a zombie, your app will crash/break to debugger and `NSLog` a message for you.

For more information, check out this CocoaDev page:  http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled

Also, this process will become much easier with the release of 10.6 and the next versions of Xcode and Instruments.  Just saying'.  =)

Comment: Totally agreed. The new Zombies instrument is very nice.

Answer (score 22):

Product > Profile will pop up Instruments. Select zombies from the panel and go nuts.

Comment: @jluebbert I'd say try harder because I definitely see it, running Xcode 4.02

Answer (score 17):

Go to **Product - Scheme - edit scheme - Arguments - Environment Variables** set **NSZombieEnabled = YES**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12):

In xcode 4.2

Goto, Product -> edit scheme -> click Run yourappname.app -> Diagonostics -> Enable Zombie object.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a video and explaination how to use Instruments and NSZombie to find and fix memory crashes on iOS:
http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/

Answer (score 6):

As of Xcode 3.2.5 and Snow Leopard (Mac OS X 10.6), you can run your code through the Zombies instrument: `Run > Run with Performance Tool > Zombies`. That allows you to see particular objects and their retain counts on a timeline.

Comment: I can see zombies option but it is grayed out. Do you know how it is enabled?

Comment: @RahulVyas, I've never seen that before, but do you have garbage collection turned on? I could see Zombies not making sense in that context

Comment: I have turned on garbage collection in the settings it shows supported [-fobjc-gc] but still that option is disabled. Infact only last 5 options are enabled in the instruments category. Any other idea? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @RahulVyas: Sorry, to be clearer, I thought turning garbage collection _off_ would possibly enable Zombies, since I don't think it's possible to have a zombie with garbage collection. If that doesn't solve it, I would recommend reading the Instruments documentation (they have good write-ups on each instrument) and if you still haven't gotten it, post a question here to get wider attention (and ultimately an answer).

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 4.5.2 goto Product -> Edit Scheme -> and Under the Diagnostics tab check the check box in between Objective C and Enable Zombie Objects and Click on OK

Answer (score 3):

To enable Zombie logging double-click the executable in the executables group of your Xcode project. At this point click the Arguments tab and in the `Variables to be set in the environment:` section, make a variable called `NSZombieEnabled` and set its value to `YES`.

Answer (score 3):

In XCode 4.0: To detect NSZombie in Instruments, select the Simulator as your target (can't detect NSZomboe on device). Run Instruments (CMD+I) and select "Zombies" trace template. Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

In the preferences of your executable add the environment variable `NSZombieEnabled` and set the value to `YES`.

Answer (score 2):

in ur XCODE (4.3) next the play button :) (run)

select : edit scheme

the scheme management window will open

click on the Arguments tab

you should see : 1- Arguments passed on launch
                 2- environment variables

inside the the (2- environment variables) place 
Name: NSZombieEnabled
Value: YES

And its done....

Answer (score 1):

NSZombieEnabled is used for Debugging BAD_ACCESS,

enable the NSZombiesEnabled environment variable from Xcode’s schemes sheet.

`Click on Product⇒Edit Scheme to open the sheet and set the Enable Zombie Objects check box`

this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUeATdeWZKs&list=PLrUFyg1unBb85La4kt3rbDw5sNJi4bwte&index=1) will help you to see what i'm trying to say.

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks updated my answers with the appropriate setting